# Oracle 12c - select rows with multiple values in a group

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
select ssn, count(*) 
from (
  select ssn, employee_id, is_active 
  from employee 
  where is_active ='Y'
)
group by ssn
having count(*) > 1
```

I want to modify this query to find all `ssn`'s that exist in the table more than once BUT with different `employee_id`'s, with at least one record having `is_active` of Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No subquery or CTE is needed, just `group by` and `having`:

```
select ssn, count(*) 
from employee
group by ssn
having min(employee_id) <> max(employee_id) and
       sum(case when is_active ='Y' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the details then:

```
SELECT ssn,
       employee_id,
       is_active 
FROM   (
  SELECT ssn,
         employee_id,
         is_active,
         COUNT( DISTINCT employee_id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ssn ) AS num_emps,
         COUNT( CASE is_active WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ssn )
           AS num_active
  FROM   employee
)
WHERE  num_emps > 1
AND    num_active > 0
```

If you just want the `ssn`s then:

```
SELECT ssn
FROM   employee
GROUP BY ssn
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT employee_id ) > 1
AND    COUNT( CASE is_active WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 END ) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use windowed `COUNT` to get number of distinct employees and `SUM` to handle at least on active:

```
WITH cte AS(
  select ssn, employee_id,
   COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) OVER(PARTITION BY ssn) AS cnt,
   SUM(CASE WHEN is_active ='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY ssn) AS s_active
  from employee 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1 AND s_active > 1;
```

Comment: This will only get `ssn` when there are multiple active employees who have different `employee_id`s

Comment: The OP said "at least one" of the rows with distinct `employee_id` must have `is_active = 'Y'`. Your query doesn't do that - it looks for at least two rows, both with `is_active = 'Y'`, and with distinct `employee_id`.

Comment: Of course, the `HAVING` clause exists precisely so you don't have to use an inner-query outer-query arrangement like this.

Comment: @mathguy Yes, but I wanted to show entire row (ssn, employee_id, is_active) to have full picture instead of only (ssn, count)

Comment: Understood, but the OP wanted to modify his query, which was just `select ssn, count(*)`. Different tools are appropriate for different business requirements.

Comment: @mathguy Probably yes, but I bet that next query OP would write would be like `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE ssn=?` where ssn is from aggregated version to see actual rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly this should do

```
select TMP.*
from (
  select CASE WHEN MIN(employee_id) OVER( PARTITION BY ssn) <>
                   MAX(employee_id) OVER( PARTITION BY ssn) THEN 'Y'
              ELSE 'N'
          END AS hasMultipleDistinctEmployees,
         CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN is_active = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                     ( PARTITION BY ssn ) = 1 THEN 'Y' 
              ELSE 'N'
          END AS hasAtLeaseOneActive,
  ssn, employee_id, is_active 
  from employee 
) TMP
WHERE hasMultipleDistinctEmployees = 'Y'
  AND hasAtLeaseOneActive = 'Y'
```